# Do I need to restructure my project directories to work with composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

For the past 5 years or so, I've settled into the habit of structuring my web projects as such:

```
/var/www/project/
                /project.com/
                            /index.php
                            /images/
                /project.inc/
                            /vendor/
                            /classes/
                            /pages/
                            /models/
```

You get the idea. It's my own hacked up mvc-like system. project.com is the only directory that's web-accessible. Most other things are behind the scenes, and I like it like that. However - lately I've started tinkering with composer. I cannot find any feasible way to house composer under project.inc. Looking through composer's setup and reading through the docs ... am I correct in assuming that composer absolutely has to be in the projects webroot? Is there no way around this?

Comment: Composer doesn't have to be in the web root, what problem specifically have you run into putting it in your project.inc directory?

Comment: The composer vendor directory is actually suggested to keep out of web reach.
Just make sure to require the `vendor/autoload.php` file to boot up composer for your application. If you're asking how to autoload your own classes and models through composer, you can autoload your custom stuff as either psr4, psr0, classmap, or specific files: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading
What specific problem are you running into?

Comment: ah - ok, so I've got this all backwards then. Sounds like I just need to go back through the instructions. I just haven't been able to access the packages I've installed.

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, you are referring to the composer.json which is just a build configuration file.  I would argue that it doesn't belong in either of your directories because it is not a web file (project.com) nor is it php code to be included at execution time (project.inc).

Be that as it may, it doesn't matter where you place it.  As for setting the location of the vendor directory you can do that in the config section of the composer.json

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "project.inc/vendor"
    }
}
```

I'd still recommend you take a look at symfony and laravel and the structure and conventions they use.  They address the same things you wanted to address, and even a few things you don't explicitly address.

Comment: oh. Alright, I was under the impression that the composer.json file was for composer to modify and structure; not to be messed with. Alright - this is making much more sense now. Thanks.